# Noun version of 'Compel'?

Tags: nouns, vocabulary

I want to say a word 'compellance' or 'compelation', but I don't know what the correct word is.

Comment: What's the problem with *compulsion*?

Comment: @Kris, (from one Kris to another), what's the problem with courteousness? :-)  If you're old enough and from the US, you might remember the song, "Try a Little Tenderness" - particularly with our new community members!

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'm not young enough for frivolity any more :) In any case, was that comment above *rude*? Who'd a thunk!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest noun form of compel is [compulsion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compulsion). It is most commonly associated with psychological drives.

Comment: So what's a good word that doesn't have this negative connotation?

Comment: Compel has a negative connotation so it seems to me that the noun form having a similar negative connatation is appropriate.  You might use "drive" or "tendancy" but neither of them is a good match for "compel"

Answer (score 2):

Compeller: a person or a reason behind the force or drive. "Father was a compeller, a man who would not be disobeyed." Keeps the Latin root of *com* (with) + *pellere* (to drive or force) but retains the reason behind the action.

Answer (score 0):

*[Impetus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impetus#Noun)* (“force, either internal or external, that impels; an impulse”) should serve.  Some words found in definitions of several of those words may also work: *[push](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/push#Noun)*, *[thrust](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thrust#Noun)*, *[urge](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/urge#Noun)*, *[force](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/force#Noun)*, *[stimulus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stimulus#Noun)*, *[impulse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impulse#Noun)*.